# CQRS and service bus

Tags: cqrs

CQRS is about separating commands and queries. We can add it easily using several patterns & technologies like Event Sourcing, DDD, NoSQL, etc... but is ServiceBus mandatory?

Comment: It's not mandatory and often not necessary.
For instance I use Event Store to store events, write on streams with optimistic concurrency, read streams, subscribe to events (this already makes the service bus optional), replay events, etc.
You can use some kind of message bus but you'll face distributed transactions issues soon (e.g: what happens if an event is stored properly in an event storage but the app goes down just before broadcasting the message?) That's where Event Store comes handy, the save & publish is atomic.

Comment: You could use it to broadcast events in a real-time event-driven scenario so that other bounded contexts can subscribe to certain events. Of course a message bus is not ideal for replaying events, just to guarantee delivery.
Some people use them for commands but I've never understood that since commands are naturally synchronous (e.g: unlike events, commands can be rejected) and therefore there's no advantage of putting them in any queue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd say messaging and a service bus is optional.

CQRS simply means decomposing your application so that the Read and Write parts of your application can be optimized for the respective concern. Commands can be handled directy, even Events, if you decide to use them, can be dispatched synchronously.

A good reference for using an internal dispatcher is [Greg Young's simple examle](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r).

**Update:** [Rob Ashton has just posted a very good article](http://codeofrob.com/archive/2011/09/28/cqrs-is-too-complicated.aspx) on what CQRS is and how not to make it more complicated than it actually is.

Answer (score 2):

No serviceBus is not mandatory, it's simply one of the technologies that be used to implement CQRS, for example Event Pub/Sub.  If anything, Event Sourcing & DDD have a closer relationship to CQRS than ServiceBus.

Comment: CQRS is based on CQS, but how can we say that doing CQS is doing CQRS ? according to gregory youngs, I remember him saying in one of his webcast presenting CQRS that CQRS is different than CQS in that it is at the architectural level. What does it means if the use of DDD, Event Sourcing are optionals ?

Comment: CQRS is an application of CQS on an architectural level. Bertrand Meyer's CQS principle is being applied on method level and in itself has few architectural implications. To minimize confusion I'd take CQRS and CQS as being completely separate because the level where it's being applied is so different. Similar is only the underlying principle itself: Asking a question should not change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can use CQRS without service bus. In your case you only need the command dispatcher and the query dispatcher

Comment: Query dispatcher?